# Which properties to use in API Gateway Proxy Request Event when developing AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When API Gateway is integrated with AWS Lambda function using Lambda proxy integration, the Lambda function will receive the HTTP request information in the `event` variable. An example of the `event` variable content can be found on AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-api-gateway-request).

In the AWS example, the same value is appeared twice in the `event` variable but on different properties:

- Property `httpMethod` and property `requestContext.httpMethod` are both having the same value `GET`
- Property `resource` and property `requestContext.resourcePath` are both having the same value `/{proxy+}`

My question is, if I want to get the HTTP method and the resource path, which properties should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of those. Whichever is more convenient and makes more sense in your code.

They are included both as `event` properties and as `requestContext` properties because they are *semantically* part of both.

Comment: Is there any AWS documentation you found for `event` and `requestContext`? I tried to find them but failed :(

Comment: It's the link in your question. :-)